# Can you create an event in a user control, if so, how?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have created a User Control containing a DatePicker and I want create an event in the user control linking to the DatePicker DateChanged event.  This custom user control will be used in an itemscontrol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Add a public event to the control. And then add a method that looks for delegates attached to the event.  If there are any delegates, raise the event.  Here's an example:

**In the User Control:**

```
public partial class Controls_UserComments : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    // the event delegates may listen for
    public event EventHandler CommentEditing;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // handle an event in the user control and bubble the event up to any delegates
        GridView_Comments.RowCancelingEdit += new GridViewCancelEditEventHandler(GridView_Comments_RowCancelingEdit);
    }

    void GridView_Comments_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView_Comments.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView_Comments.DataBind();

        // raise the event for attached delegates
        if (CommentEditing != null)
            CommentEditing(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

**Now, in the web form utilizing the user control:**

```
<ppc:UserComments ID="UserComments_ObservationComments" runat="server"
    OnCommentEditing="RefreshComments"
    />
```

Good luck!